# Does the number of records have any impact on performance

Tags: database, performance, sqlite

does the number of records from a db affect the speed of select queries?

i mean if a db has 50 records and another one has 5 million records, will the selects from the 2nd one be slower? assuming i have all the indexes in the right place

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it doesn't have to be a large penalty.

At the most basic level an index is a b-tree.  Performance is somewhat correlated to the number of levels in the b-tree, so a 5 record database has about 2 levels, a 5 million record database has about 22 levels.  But it's binary, so a 10 million row database has 23 levels, and really, index access times are typically not the problem in performance tuning - the usual problem is tables that aren't indexed properly.

As noted by odedsh, caching is also a large contributor, and small databases will be cached well.  Sqlite stores records in primary key sequence, so picking a primary key that allows records that are commonly used together to be stored together can be a big benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it matters for the reasons the others said.

There's other things that can effect the speed of Select statements to, such as how many columns you're grabbing data from.

I once did some speed tests in a table with over 150 columns, where I needed to grab only  about 40 of the columns, and I needed all 20,000+ records. While the speed differences were very minimal (we're talking 20 to 40 milliseconds), it was actually faster to grab the data from All the columns with a 'SELECT ALL *', rather than going 'Select All Field1, Field2, etc'.

I assume the more records and columns in your table, the greater the speed difference this example will net you, but I never had a need to test it any farther in more extreme cases like 5 million records in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If a table is tiny and the entire db is tiny when you select anything from the table it is very likely that all the data is in memory already and the result can be returned immediately.

If the table is huge but you have an index and you are doing a simple select on the indexed columns then the index can be scanned then the correct blocks can be read from disk and the result returned.

If there is no index that can be used then the db will do a full table scan reading the table block by block looking for matches.

If there is a partial map between the index columns and the select query columns then the db can try to minimize the number of blocks that should be read. And a lot of thought can be placed into properly choosing the indexes structure and type (BITMAP / REGULAR)

And this is just for the most basic SQL that selects from a single table without any calculations.